# How to retrieve values after # in a URL using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to implement ajax back/forward button support and therefore writing variables after a # in my url. I would also like the user to be able to copy the url and then link back to it. Does anyone know how can I parse the url and grab my "querystrings" even though they are behind a #?

Comment: I am trying to get the value on the server side. I can already get it on the client side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value after the hash is not transmitted to the server. There's another SO question about that somewhere, but I'm having trouble finding it. Likewise it's taken me a while to find a decent reference to cite, but [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) has some confirmation:

> The fragment identifier functions
>   differently than the rest of the URI:
>   namely, its processing is exclusively
>   client-side with no participation from
>   the server. When an agent (such as a
>   Web browser) requests a resource from
>   a Web server, the agent sends the URI
>   to the server, but does not send the
>   fragment.

I assume you want to respond to it on the server side rather than the browser side? (Given that you're asking about doing it in C#...)

Answer (score 7):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment.aspx